# laravel date search filter cannot display data between dates

Tags: php, laravel, random, laravel-5.5

when i run my **date range filter** between dates no data show, but inside my database i have those data.

**Note:** *if u know how to use carbon please state below thanks.*

Example: From: 1-5-2018 to 31-5-2018 it will show nothing, please see image below

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cw14.jpg)

**CONTROLLER:**

```
 if ($request->has('from') && $request->has('to')) {
        $from = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($request->get('from')));
        $to = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($request->get('to')));
        $leads = Lead::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->paginate(5);
    }
```

Comment: Make sure in `whereBetween()` smaller date is placed first and than greater

Comment: yeah but data still empty ..

Comment: Are date formats same in DB and variables?

Comment: im using my sql default format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: And in your variables?

Answer (score 0):

Use toDateString instead of strtotime. This will work.

```
 if ($request->has('from') && $request->has('to')) {
            $from = $request->get('from')->toDateString();
            $to = $request->get('to')->toDateString();
            $leads = Lead::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->paginate(5);
        }
```

Ps: can't open imgur right now. Can't see your date types, if this didn't work and can't found any solution add your date form please.

Comment: i'm having this error "Call to a member function toDateString() on string"

Comment: what you see in your if statment with die dump
 dd(date('d-M-Y', strtotime($request->get('from'))));